# Enable crop of image at on click jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this part of js code:

```
var bool = 0;

$('#imageToCrop').cropper({
          autoCrop: false,
          movable: false,
          viewMode: 3,
          crop: function(e) {
            // Output the result data for cropping image.
            console.log(e.x);
            console.log(e.y);
            console.log(e.width);
            console.log(e.height);
            console.log(e.rotate);
            console.log(e.scaleX);
            console.log(e.scaleY);

          },
          cropend: function (e) {
              if (bool == 0) {
              $('#cropTimetable').toggle();
              $('#clearCrop').toggle();
              $('#downloadTimetable').toggle();
              $('#downloadHDTimetable').toggle();
              bool = 1;
            }
          }          

    });
```

This is the initialization code for the crop plugin Cropper that I took [here](https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/).

I would enable the cropper only if I click on this text (jsp code):

```
<li id="cropImage" style="cursor: pointer;cursor: hand;" class="col-sm-2 col-xs-1">
    <a><span style="vertical-align:top">Crop Image</span></a>
</li>
```

I can do this? Enable the crop when I click on the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work by wrapping the initialization code inside an onclick function like:

```
$("#cropImage").on("click", {id : "imageToCrop"}, initCropperOnImage);

function initCropperOnImage(event)
{
   //get the id from event.data
   $(event.data.id).cropper({
      autoCrop: false,
      movable: false,
      viewMode: 3,
      crop: function(e) {
        // Output the result data for cropping image.
        console.log(e.x);
        console.log(e.y);
        console.log(e.width);
        console.log(e.height);
        console.log(e.rotate);
        console.log(e.scaleX);
        console.log(e.scaleY);

      },
      cropend: function (e) {
          if (bool == 0) {
          $('#cropTimetable').toggle();
          $('#clearCrop').toggle();
          $('#downloadTimetable').toggle();
          $('#downloadHDTimetable').toggle();
          bool = 1;
        }
      }          

  });
}
```